# How to automate Angular js application and handle wait i.e synchronization using selenium webdriver and java instead of using Protractor

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to automate Angular js application using selenium webdriver and java.Also i need to handle synchronization i.e  wait for angular element as we handle it for non angular js application.

Kindly suggest me the possible solution which will find angular js element, handle waits and perform operation using selenium webdriver and java.

Thank you.

Comment: What does this question mean? First, using selenium and related webdrivers, whatever will be the programming language (Java for example), you can always access all the elements through standard selectors etc... 
Then "automate AngularJS application using selenium WebDriver and Java" what does it mean? 
Then why protractor is limiting your tasks? It is more than enough for interacting with AngularJS applications, and if you have anything else to do, you can always link some `node.js` code for example or call something outside, start other processes/applications.

Comment: While automating angular js application using selenium webdriver and java,it can not wait until angular js application is loaded. So that i need solution to automate using selenium webdriver and java

Comment: Protractor uses javascript language so that we can not perform exception handling as javascript itself does not catch all exceptions and we can not do multi threading.

Comment: "protractor uses javascript so we cannot perform exceptions handling": FALSE. JavaScript has try catch.

Comment: "While automating angular js application using selenium webdriver and java,it can not wait until angular js application is loaded": FALSE. You can wait for it simply using browser waiting assertions in order to wait for some element in the page displayed after angularjs is loaded

Comment: And again, from protractor you can run a Java program passing simply through node.js (protractor is built on node.js) and perform from the Java application whatever you want to

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found some time before in SO and use it quite successful to wait for angular.

```
final String script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
            "var rootSelector = \'body\';\n" +
            "var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n" +
            "\n" +
            "try {\n" +
            "    if (angular) {\n" +
            "        window.angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "    else {\n" +
            "        callback();\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "} catch (err) {\n" +
            "    callback(err.message);\n" +
            "}";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeAsyncScript(script, new Object[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ngDriver: https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver, with buid upon selenium WebDriver.